# Navigate with Vue router-link changing only query parameters, not path

Tags: vue.js, query-string

In Vue.js, I'm using `<router-link>` to navigate, as such:

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/', query: { q: item.id, lang: lang } }">{{item.name}}</router-link>
```

This does not update the path, only the query string. Although the resulting URL is formatted correctly, it does not trigger navigation in Vue, apparently because the path has not changed, only the query string.

If I put a beforeRouteUpdate hook on my component, I can see that the new query parameters appear in the "to" object.

How can I make Vue perform the navigation, even though only the query parameters have changed?

Comment: This is because Vue reuses components when possible.  Is there a reason you want the navigation to happen?  Perhaps wanting the created/mounted hook to fire again?

Answer (score 2):

You have most probably solved this already, so this answer could be useful for others with this problem.

Documentation link - [In-Component Guards - beforeRouteUpdate](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)

> If I put a beforeRouteUpdate hook on my component, I can see that the new query parameters appear in the "to" object

This means you doing it all correctly since you are seeing the new parameters in the component guard, So next, what you need to do is to do as prescribed below in docs and example

[Fetching After Navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation)

So all you now have to do is fetch your new data using these new parameters

```
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
     this.post = null
     // replace `getItem` with your data fetching util / API wrapper

     getItem(to.params.q, to.params.lang, (err, post) => {
       this.post = post
     next()
  })
 }
```